# Write-only `glMapBuffer`, what if I don't write it all?

Tags: opengl

Say I've got a buffer object with some data in it.

I use `glMapBuffer` with `GL_WRITE_ONLY` and write to every second byte (think interleaved vertex attributes).

Then I `glUnmapBuffer` the buffer.

Are the bytes I didn't write to preserved or are they now undefined?

I'm wondering because the main purpose of `GL_WRITE_ONLY` seems to be to avoid transferring the previous content of the buffer from the card's memory to main memory. The driver, however, has no way of knowing to which bytes I've actually written something in order to update the buffer only partially.

So either the driver transfers the content to main memory first, rendering `GL_WRITE_ONLY` pointless on pretty much every platform I could think of. Or it is assumed that I write the complete mapped area. Yet no such obligation is mentioned in the man pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: The data is preserved.

> I'm wondering because the main purpose of GL_WRITE_ONLY seems to be to
>   avoid transferring the previous content of the buffer from the card's
>   memory to main memory.

Well, the implementation has many potential ways to fullfill that request, and the access flags may help in the decision of which path to go. For example, the driver may decide to do some direct I/O mapping of the buffer in VRAM instead of using system RAM for the mapping.

The issues you see with this are actually addressed by the more modern [`glMapBufferRange()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml) API introduced in the [`GL_ARB_map_buffer_range`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/map_buffer_range.txt) extension. Although the name might suggest that this is for mapping parts of the buffers, it actually superseeds the `glMapBuffer()` function completely and allows for a much finer control. For example, the `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT` or `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT` flags mark the data as invalid and enable for the optimizations you had in mind for the general `GL_WRITE_ONLY` case. But  without these, the data is to be preserved, and how this is done is the implementation's problem.

Comment: In addition to derhass very good answer: don't write every second byte in a write only buffer. If the buffer is directly mapped to VRAM, write combining will be used and you will get very slow writes if you don't write big contiguous chunks. It's better to write all of it in this case, even if half the values don't change. Or make 2 buffers.

Comment: Thanks! How does direct VRAM mapping work internally? I know that DME allows the card to directly access the main memory, I wasn't aware that there is a way to do the opposite. @Jerem, thanks for the warning! I'll read up on write combining.